# how to add "/*! */ " in object key while splitting string?

Tags: javascript

I am splitting my string and convert it into javascript obj . but my key miss this `character /*! */` .

here is my string and splitter function

```js
const a = "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}";

const result = {},
  temp = a.split(/\/\*\!\s*(.*?)\s*\*\//).slice(1);
while (temp.length) result[temp.shift()] = temp.shift();

console.log(result);
```

**My output**

```
{"###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ######################################################":"","MISC + SASS":"a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}","GENERIC - BGIMG":".bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}","CG2111 - test":"span{color:red}","CG2112 - test":"span{color:red}","INFO":"#id{content:'1.1.1'}"}
```

**Expected ouput**

```
 {
  "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### */": "",
  "/*! MISC + SASS */": "a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}",
  "/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */": ".bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}",
  "/*! CG2111 - test */": "span{color:red}",
  "/*! CG2112 - test */": "span{color:red}",
  "/*! INFO */": "#id{content:'1.1.1'}"
}
```

Comment: Your regex can be simplified to `/\/\*\!(.*?)\*\//`. It does seems to correctly to correctly match the key values required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your matches start with `/*!` followed by a space, so match those characters up until lookahead matches the same `/*!` or the end of the string.

```js
const a = "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}";

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  [...a.matchAll(/(\/\*! .*?\*\/)(.*?)(?=\/\*! |$)/g)]
    .map(([, key, value]) => [key, value])
);
console.log(result);
```

- `\/\*!` - match a literal `/`, followed by a literal `*`, followed by `*`
- - match a literal space
- `.*?` - match as few characters as possible up until
- `(?=\/\*! |$)` lookahead matches

  - `\/\*!` - the same beginning characters, or
  - `$` - the end of the string

Comment: but this is not expected output .. I need a object . not array

Comment: Oh, I missed the colons. The strings are very very long. Use `matchAll` instead, and capture the key and the value separately so you can combine them into an object with `Object.fromEntries`

Answer (score 1):

ES6 answer:

```js
const a = "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO */#id{content:'1.1.1'}";

const map = a.split('/*!').slice(1) // break into each item per key-value pair
  .map(str => str.split('*/')) // separate key and value
  .map(([key, value]) => [`/*!${key}*/`, value]) // add back delimiters
  .reduce((map, [key, value]) => ({...map, [key]: value}), {}); // merge into a map

console.log(map);
```

Output:

```
{
  "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### */": "",
  "/*! MISC + SASS */": "a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}",
  "/*! GENERIC - BGIMG */": ".bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}",
  "/*! CG2111 - test */": "span{color:red}",
  "/*! CG2112 - test */": "span{color:red}",
  "/*! INFO */": "#id{content:'1.1.1'}"
}
```