# how to replace a string with empty string from in long string?

Tags: javascript

how to replace a string with empty string from in long string ?I am using replace function

but not getting expected output.

```js
var a = "/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS *//*! purgecss start ignore */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! purgecss end ignore *//*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO *//*! purgecss start ignore */#id{content:'1.1.1'}/*! purgecss end ignore */";
console.log(a)

console.log(a.replace(/\/*!purgecss start ignore*/, ''));
console.log(a.replace(/\/*!purgecss end ignore*/, ''));
console.log(a)
```

I want to replace all `/*!purgecss start ignore*/` and `/*!purgecss end ignore*/` with empty string .

Comment: didn't you get an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323928/how-to-add-in-object-key-while-splitting-string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add "/\*! \*/ " in object key while splitting string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323928/how-to-add-in-object-key-while-splitting-string)

Comment: `a.replaceAll(/\/*!purgecss start ignore*/g,'').replaceAll(/\/*!purgecss end ignore*/g,'')`

Comment: *"I want to replace `/*!purgecss"`* But......... you have `/*! purgecss` - You just offended a whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = `/*! ###################################################### # Test.cs #  RELEASE: 1.1.1 # BUILD DATE: Fri Oct 30 2020 15:25:57 GMT-0700 (PDT) # COPYRIGHT ###################################################### *//*! MISC + SASS *//*! purgecss start ignore */a:focus,button:focus,div[tabindex]:focus,li[tabindex]:focus,span[tabindex]:focus{outline-offset:2px;outline-width:2px!important;outline-style:dotted!important;outline-color:currentColor}/*! purgecss end ignore *//*! GENERIC - BGIMG */.bgimg{background-size:cover;background-position:50% 50%;background-repeat:no-repeat}/*! CG2111 - test */span{color:red}/*! CG2112 - test */span{color:red}/*! INFO *//*! purgecss start ignore */#id{content:'1.1.1'}/*! purgecss end ignore */`;

const b = a.replace(/\/\*!\s*purgecss (start|end) ignore\s*\*\//g, "");
console.log(b)
```

Learn what [characters are considered ***special***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in RegExp. Such characters should be escaped with a backslash `\`.